# isolateScope() returning undefined when testing angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

Using Angular v1.2.25 and rails asset pipeline, I am attempting to test that a directive's isolate scope has indeed been updated. Since isolateScope() returns undefined I am getting expected undefined to be defined ...'

```
describe("cool directive", function() {

  beforeEach(module('necessaryModule'));

  var scope, $rootScope, $compile, elem,
    baseElement = '<div auto="mock_a" inc="mock_p" method="mock_m" reset-method="mock_r"></div>';

  beforeEach(inject(function( _$rootScope_, _$compile_, _$httpBackend_, $http){
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    angular.extend(scope, {
      mock_a: [
        {name: "example1"},
        {name: "example2"}
      ],  
      mock_m: function(){
        return $http.get('/mockBackend', {
          params:{
            page:  scope.mockPage
          }   
        }); 
      },  
      mock_r: function() {
        scope.page = 1;
        scope.list = []; 
        load();
      },  
      mock_p: 1
    }); 
    $httpListGet = _$httpBackend_;
    $httpListGet.whenPOST('/api/something').respond({});
    $httpListGet.whenGET('/mockBackend').respond({name: "example3"});
    $httpListGet.whenGET('/mockBackend?page=1').respond({name: "example3"});
    $httpListGet.whenGET('/mockBackend?page=2').respond({name: "example4"});
  }));

    var create = function() {
      elem = angular.element(baseElement);
      compiledElement = $compile(elem)(scope);
      elem.scope().$apply();
      return compiledElement;
    };  

  it("has 'list' defined", function() {
    var compiledElem = create();
    var isolateElemScope = compiledElem.isolateScope();
    $rootScope.$apply();
    console.log('isolateElemScope',isolateElemScope);
    expect(isolateElemScope.list).toBeDefined();
  });
```

I'm expecting the directives scope to be accessible and testable, but I'm getting undefined when I test for it. Thank you.

Comment: just at first glance, I'd say get rid of `elem.scope().$apply();` from the `create` function and change `$rootScope.$apply()` to `scope.$digest()`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

to get the isolateScope I use the following code

```
compiledElem.children().scope()
```

This is because that most directives don't use `replace`, which means the `directive` tag is on the page, and the `directive implementation` is added as children of that tag. 
In that case, the isolate scope will belong to the children.

Even if that is not the case, the snippet should still work - as the children will share the parent's scope..

The only case it won't work, is an extreme scenario where you have 2 nested directives, where the inner one uses replace. but I never saw this.

Comment: you are completely correct about the nested directives.

Answer (score 0):

Other people coming to this page may have added the test to jasmine but forgotten to add a reference to their directive.

Comment: How to do it please ?